# How to get corresponding x and y values from a Seaborn Plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, seaborn

[image: lmpot using seaborn]

I have plotted a graph in jupyter notebook using seaborn lmplot and I want to extract value of Voltage(kv) at hn=0.5 but do not know how to get that.Please help

Comment: the link which u shared is with respect to distplot which only for 1 variable .I have plotted for two variables and the above link is not helping

Comment: You could call [scipy's fit function](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html) directly instead of a detour via a plot meant for visualization.